# Multiple child widgets in pyside

Tags: python, widget, parent-child, pyside, children

I want to have multiple children of one QWidget. However, when I just set a child multiple times, only the last one to be set shows up. The ultimate goal is to put this widget in a QScrollArea. Here is my current code:

```
class EditDialog(QDialog):
    def __init__(self,widget):
        super(EditDialog, self).__init__()

        self.scroller = QScrollArea()
        self.form = QWidget()
        self.lab = QLabel(self.form)
        self.lab.setText("Label")
        self.edit = QLineEdit(self.form)
        self.edit.setText("LineEdit")
        self.but = QPushButton("PushButton",self.form)
        self.scroller.setWidget(self.form)

        self.layout = QVBoxLayout()
        self.layout.addWidget(self.scroller)
        self.setLayout(self.layout)

        self.exec_()
```

However, only the QPushButton is shown. I apologize if this is a stupid question, but I couldn't find anything on Google that helped me.

**Edit:**
I have tried putting these widgets (labels, buttons and line-edits) in a layout, but once you get quite a few of them, they start to resize depending on the size of the QScrollArea. I don't want that though, I want them to stay the same size, not be dependent on the size of the QScrollArea.

Answer (score 1):

You need to add your widgets to the layout.  Something like this will add your label, line edit, and button to you layout.

```
self.layout.addWidget(self.lab)
self.layout.addWidget(self.edit)
self.layout.addWidget(self.but)
```

Comment: Yeah I thought of that too, but once you get a larger number of widgets, they resize depending on the size of the QScrollArea.